# How to specify repository branch for poetry?

Tags: python, python-poetry

I have Project A with a pyproject file like this

```
[tool.poetry]
name = "projectA"
version = "2.0"
description = "Package gathering for project A"
repository = "https://git.saas.tech/project-a"
[tool.poetry.dependencies]
Package B = "1.0"
```

I want to test a feature. How can i tell poetry to look at a specific branch ?
Is this possible ?

```
repository = "https://git.saas.tech/project-a/my-feature"
```

Answer (score 16):

I did this as described in the [docs](https://python-poetry.org/docs/dependency-specification/#git-dependencies) and it solved my problem...

`Package B= { git = "git@git.saas.tech/project-a.git", branch = "myfeature" }`